# how to make a path move along a path

Tags: animation, path, vector

Basically, I want to move sinusoid along a 3d path. It has to move with the start of the sinusoid staying in one position, basically like a vibrating string.

I could mask both ends and loop the animation, but if there is an easier option I'm happy to hear about it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please show some pictures of what you're trying to achieve